# How to modify query string in python (CGI)

Tags: python, html, cgi, query-string

I'm experimenting with cgi in Python, and I was wondering how I would modify a query string.

For example, if I had a snippit of HTML:

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/text.py" method="get">
    <textarea name="stuff"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

then the query string might be something like

```
http://www.foobar.com/cgi-bin/test.py?stuff=Some+text+here
```

If my python script returns html, how could I modify the query string to something like

```
http://www.foobar.com/cgi-bin/test.py?stuff=Some+text+here#anchor
```

so that the browser jumps down to the appropriate place in the html document that the script returns?

Comment: I think it might have to involve redirecting.

Comment: As it turned out, it did involve redirecting.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: If you have the time, it might be nice to put the solution you found as an answer to this question so that other people can benefit :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using urlparse module: http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html